# Testing Angular's index.html page is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I changed the title of my index.html page in my Angular app.  Since it is not a component is it possible to test it, and if so, how?

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animations Workshop</title>
    <base href="/">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
 <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
```

Comment: At what level? You can check the title of the page in browser-driven E2E tests, for example.

Comment: At the unit testing level, like I would a component. I also have a few divs I want to add, can I test those?

Comment: Why would you? It's static content, there's no behaviour to unit test.

Comment: You may want to look into Cypress, it makes this test simple. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-and-cypress-in-20-minutes-21be

Comment: Thank you, will do.